# Why am I getting NullPointerException in my tests?

Tags: java, class, selenium, junit

My test suite is organized into two parts: a library of test data, xpath locations for WebElements, `.click()` commands, etc. I also have a test suite.

This is an example test that shares the package it deals with for experimentation purposes. As of right this second I'm not worried about outputting results (I know how to do that), the code simply needs to work.

```
package LoginPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class FunctionCheck {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }
      @Test
      public void test() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        Thread.sleep(600);
        LoginPage.enterValidCredentials myins = new LoginPage.enterValidCredentials();
        myins.run();
      }
      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
      }
}
```

This is the class "enterValidCredentials" that sits in the same package.

```
package LoginPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class enterValidCredentials { // This class enters in a valid username and valid password on the login page.
    public void run() {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");    
    }
}
```

I got two problems:

1. In the class "enterValidCredentials", it wants me to "initialize" the driver variable. The autofix for this in Eclipse sets line 8 to `WebDriver driver = null;`.
2. Doing the above has my test throw a `NullPointerException`.

I've been searching through documentation for a while now. I'm really stumped as to what is going on. All I want is the `run()` method to literally run, and plug in the info to the page. That's the goal.

Comment: You need to initialize driver like you do in your setUp() method with the new keyword.

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions: packages have lowercase names, classes have UpperCamelCaseNames.

Comment: Until you know enough to *evaluate* Eclipse's suggested corrections, you would be well advised to ignore them.  You could even consider turning them off.  Throwing in random code that happens to make a compilation error go away will not help you learn, and will not reliably make your programs work.

Comment: @AndyTurner Wouldn't classes be namedLikeThis? I was under the impression it was always lowercaseCapital.

Comment: A quick look at the Java API should tell you not: PrintWriter, BufferedInputStream, ProcessBuilder etc. But here is Sun's page on the matter: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class enterValidCredentials {
  public void run(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");    
  }
}
```

Pass your existing `WebDriver` instance into `enterValidCredentials.run`:

```
myins.run(driver);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks man! I'm a Perl guy personally but my job requires Java so I'm still making simple mistakes like this. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem. `driver` is uninitialized. Because it is a local variable, the compiler will require you to initialize it. And when, as you said, you initialize it to null, the 2 following lines dereference it. You cannot call a method on a object that points to nothing.

```
            WebDriver driver;
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXX");
```

You must assign it a value

```
WebDriver driver = ...some object reference...;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your driver like

```
private WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

Mate, better use debug )